# Nested LinearLayouts LayoutTransition animation jumps on child removal

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-linearlayout

I've created nested LinearLayouts that contain children Buttons and other LinearLayouts with wrap_content and animateLayoutChanges set to true.

[image]

code below

When I remove a Button from a nested LinearLayout, the animation plays removing the Button but then repeats again creating jump effect in the overall nested Layout.

It seems to be a bug that occurs in API 19 and API 25 - and possibly other ones (haven't tested yet), but it works perfectly fine on API >= 27, so they must have fixed it or changed something for those versions of Android and I don't know what it is.

Problem is, I would like it to work for all APIs >= 19.

Is there any way to resolve this issue/bug or code workaround so that it works properly for those other versions of Android < API 27?

**CODE EXAMPE**

Click on Button GR1 to create a new child View (Button) in the blue LinearLayout (id = linearLayoutB) and click it again to remove that same Button to see the animation problem on any of the lower Android API versions mentioned

Click on Button R3 to to create a new child Button in the grey LinearLayout (id = linearLayoutGR) which isn't nested in any other LinearLayouts, but is able to add and remove that child Button without any animation problems for any Android version that supports LayoutTransition of course!

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutGR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#ddd"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGR1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="GR1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutR"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#fdd"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnR1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="R1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnR2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="R2"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnR3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="R3"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutG"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#dfd"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnG1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="G1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnG2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="G2"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#ddf"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnB1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B1"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnB2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="B2"/>

            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnR5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="R5" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutP"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#fdf"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnP1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="P1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnP2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="P2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGR4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="GR4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.animation.LayoutTransition;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout linearLayoutGR;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutR;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutG;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutB;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutP;

private Button btnGR1, btnR3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayoutGR = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutGR);
    linearLayoutR = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutR);
    linearLayoutG = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutG);
    linearLayoutB = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutB);
    linearLayoutP = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutP);

    linearLayoutGR.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    linearLayoutR.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    linearLayoutG.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    linearLayoutB.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    linearLayoutP.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

    btnGR1 = findViewById(R.id.btnGR1);
    btnR3 = findViewById(R.id.btnR3);

    final Button aBtn = new Button(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(131, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    aBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
    aBtn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    aBtn.setText("A");


    final Button bBtn = new Button(this);

    bBtn.setLayoutParams(params);
    bBtn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    bBtn.setText("B");


    btnGR1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (linearLayoutB.getChildCount() < 3) {
                linearLayoutB.addView(aBtn);
            } else {
                linearLayoutB.removeView(aBtn);
            }
        }
    });

    btnR3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (linearLayoutGR.getChildCount() < 5) {
                linearLayoutGR.addView(bBtn);
            } else {
                linearLayoutGR.removeView(bBtn);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

If there's some workaround I would still like to keep the same effect/behavior that it has now without that bug, where any child views (Buttons and other LinearLayouts) that are added or removed into any of the other nested Layouts causes all layouts to resize accordingly with smooth animations while keeping all child views centered and compact together

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the child removal seems to be that it's animation is delayed - looking in LayoutTrasition mChangingDisappearingDelay is set to DEFAULT_DURATION of 300ms

By setting LayoutTransition object to a delay of 0 with the code

```
layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, 0);
```

the LinearLayouts seem to animate properly again.

Each LinearLayout must have their own unique LayoutTransition object - you can't give them the same LayoutTransition object, so I created a method for that below

```
private LayoutTransition createLayoutTransition(){
    LayoutTransition layoutTransition = new LayoutTransition();
    layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

    // the delay fix
    layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, 0);
    return layoutTransition;
}
```

and then set each of the LinearLayouts LayoutTransition to the method above

```
linearLayoutGR.setLayoutTransition(createLayoutTransition());
linearLayoutR.setLayoutTransition(createLayoutTransition());
linearLayoutG.setLayoutTransition(createLayoutTransition());
linearLayoutB.setLayoutTransition(createLayoutTransition());
linearLayoutP.setLayoutTransition(createLayoutTransition());
```

replacing the old code below with the code above

```
linearLayoutGR.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
linearLayoutR.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
linearLayoutG.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
linearLayoutB.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
linearLayoutP.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

Now it seems to work on all APIs that support LayoutTransition